# Getting '502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)' error on AWS EC2 instance while deploying Django app

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, connection-timeout

My Django App deploy on AWS EC2 instance There I install nginx server
this in nginx.conf file`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens of

proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300;

proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

But When I make a request to server for bulk data manipulation it gives me this error I confirmed that this is timeout issue. Because it well running on local server

I put these line

```
proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300;
```

and the error.log file give this error

`12899 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: clientIp, server: _, request: "POST /myadmin/action HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9090/myadmin/action, host: ""`

What should I do more I tried this code also

```
proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```